# htaccess remove uma barra (/) da url ao utilizar WWW no prestashop

Tags: htaccess, apache, url, e-commerce

Tenho uma instalação prestashop versão 1.7.6 com multiloja ativado.

A princípio, o prestashop configurou o htaccess já. Cada loja é acessada da seguinte forma:

- https://meudominio.com/loja-a
- https://meudominio.com/loja-b

acontece que, ao tentar utilizar www (www.meudominio.com/loja-x), o htaccess deveria redirecionar para https correto?

no domínio principal ele consegue fazer isso:

de:
- www.meudominio.com

para:
- https://meudominio.com

agora, quando tento acessar uma loja com www, o htaccess remove a barra da URL. o resultado é esse:

de:
- www.meudominio.com/loja-x

para:
- https://meudominio.comloja-x

Alguém ja enfrentou algum problema parecido?
Tem alguma dica de como resolver?

Eu não sei mexer no htacces, ja tentei algumas coisas mas sem sucesso.

segue o trecho do htacces que eu acredito que está fazendo essas alterações:

.htaccess

//-------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudominio.com$

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudominio.com$

RewriteRule ^demo$ /demo/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudominio.com$

RewriteRule ^demo/(.*) /$1 [L]

//-------------------------------------------------------------

o meu htaccess tem vários trechos iguais a esse, porém é um para cada loja que tenho registrada.. o próprio prestashop que criou essas configurações.

No caso acima, é uma regra para a loja chamada "demo"
Apenas substitui meu domínio real por "meudominio"

Comment: Já tentou: 
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudominio.com$`, [veja aqui](https://htaccessbook.com/htaccess-redirect-https-www/)
...

Comment: Sim, eu havia verificado esse artigo anteriormente. Mas não consegui resolver, eu também verifiquei sobre configurações de DNS achando que pudesse ser o problema. Depois de várias tentativas eu acredito que realmente seja algo no htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta assim:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?meudominio\.com$

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?meudominio\.com$

RewriteRule ^demo$ /demo/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?meudominio\.com$

RewriteRule ^demo/(.*) /$1 [L]

//-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ivan, eu tentei utilizar o código acimas mas o problema continuou o mesmo.
Reiniciei o apache e limpei o cache do prestashop.
Será que o problema está em outro trecho do htaccess?
Tem um trecho que está no início do arquivo que parece algumas regras mais gerais..
segue o trecho:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

#Domain: meudominio.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meudominio.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Acho estranho você dizer que o .htaccess remover a barra, porque, pela lógica, o .htaccess possui uma regra de reescrita, mas na verdade ele só é um interpretador de como deve receber o valor e, ele não remove barras, ele apenas redireciona para a maneira da reescrita que foi definida na regra. Entenda que ele não cria nada, ela se baseia na entrada que vem, e envia a saída que vc mascara.

Comment: Você está me dizendo quando quando vc acessa um endereço com www na frente, ele está removendo a barra, eu não consigo entender, como vc está acessando esse endereço, é um link na sua página? Ou quando bate no link normal, ele está reescrevendo para esse sem barra?

Comment: eu digito no navegador "www.meudominio.com/loja-x", ai eu recebo uma resposta 301 que é de redirecionamento não é? só que eu sou redirecionado para o endereço "https://meudominio.comloja-x" e ai então da um erro, pois esse endereço não existe. se eu adicionar a barra nesse endereço final ai funciona. eu pensei que era o htaccess que "formatava" a url nova para a qual eu seria redirecionado.. mas se não for ele que está me redirecionando para essa url errada, então não sei onde procurar, vou olhar novamente as configs no dns